# Can't access site

Tags: asp.net

[image]

I can not access our payroll after buying a new router.

Comment: Pakisulat ang iyong katanungan sa tamang Ingles. Please write your question in proper English, also provide [mcve] (including related code snippets).

Comment: Please refer the link `https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask` for more information on how to ask a question more clearly here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the site in Sites tree and go to Manage Website > Advanced Settings. In the following box, under Physical Path Credentials, specify the username and password of local user that has access to the site directory. After this, the authorization error will be gone.

Comment: Sir! Every time i put username and password, it says Invalid, i try all the Password format but its not acceptable